# jQuery Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So im getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined on this site: http://baybridgeinn.com

This is a WordPress site and I have included a screenshot of what chrome debugger points to. Someone said it might be related to the Api keys warning but I dont think that is connected to it. Would appreciate any help.  [image: error screenshot]

Comment: This means you left out the function argument in a `$.each()` call. Go up the stack to see where you're calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following in your Javascript:

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').each().addClass("ga-phone");
```

`.each()` requires a function argument, so it should be:

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ga-phone");
});
```

But you don't need to use `.each()`, because jQuery setters will automatically loop through all the elements in the collection. So it should just be:

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').addClass("ga-phone");
```